# Can I put cancel and update for two different event in a single .ics file?

Tags: java, calendar, outlook, gmail, icalendar

I have an .ics file which has two events. Find below the sample content of the ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:27bant11-eda5-45b5-8b38-95e3d9a4ec55
DTSTART:20150410T160000
DTEND:20150410T163000
DESCRIPTION: Test1
SUMMARY:CU Instrument 1 (515000011)
TRANSP: OPAQUE
CLASS:PUBLIC
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20150409T142630
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:29bant11-eda5-45b5-8b38-95e3d9a4ec35
DTSTART:20150410T150000
DTEND:20150410T153000
DESCRIPTION:Test 2
SUMMARY:CU Instrument 2 (515000010)
TRANSP: OPAQUE
CLASS:PUBLIC
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20150409T132630
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It is clear from the above sample that I have two events. When I save the content as sample.ics and sending to someone's mailbox(I am using gmail). It is adding two events at one go.

I heard that I need to use

```
METHOD: CANCEL
STATUS: CANCELLED
```

together to cancel an event and

```
SEQUENCE:1
```

to update a newly created event.

Now my question is can I cancel the first event and update the second event using a single ics file. Is it possible to do the same at one go? Any help will be much appreciated.

Swarup

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to send two separate emails since METHOD header can only be present once in a VCALENDAR part.